# Searching any word using Linq

Tags: c#, performance, linq, search

In my winform app I have a form where user can search for product by typing any text in search field. For example the product description might be stored as `"Adidas aftershave 100Ml"` . But user can type any thing like `100 Ml Aftershave`. So I would like to query using linq to get all records where description contains any of these word(`100 Ml Aftershave`).

So far I have done something like this:

```
List<string>txtList =  txtSearchTerm.Text.Split(' ').ToList();
return dbContext.productRepo.Where(t => txtList.Any(b =>
                   t.ProductDescription.StartsWith(b)
                   || t.ProductDescription.EndsWith(b)
                   || t.ProductDescription.Contains(b)

                 )).Select(x => x.ProductDescription).ToList();
```

Any other way of achieving this in better way ,making it more quick or any other improvement.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could use just one IndexOf != -1

Comment: You could build a regex based on your txtSearchTerm and use that to match the target string. .*(100|Ml|Aftershave).* would give a match on "Adidas aftershave 100Ml"

Comment: `Contains` will cover both the `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` cases.

Comment: You might consider using your database's native "full text search" capabilities. E.g. Oracle has [Oracle Text](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/index-098492.html) and apparently MS SQL has something similar.

Comment: good idea , not sure how to use it in linq if I enable full-text indexed in MSSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are testing if the description starts, ends and contains something. The first two are already redundant because `Contains` "contains" them:

```
var matchingDescriptions = dbContext.productRepo
    .Where(x => txtList.Any(x.ProductDescription.Contains))
    .Select(x => x.ProductDescription));
```

Another easy optimization(for Linq-To-Objects), I would order the words by length first:

```
var txtList = txtSearchTerm.Text.Split(' ').OrderBy(s => s.Length).ToList()
```

Comment: Not sure how ordering the word list would help since this seems to be EF and thus will be translated to SQL anyway.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can straightaway improve is to remove `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` , Becuase you are already doing `t.ProductDescription.Contains(b)` .

```
List<string>txtList =  txtSearchTerm.Text.Split(' ').ToList();
       return dbContext.productRepo.Where(t => txtList.Any(b =>                 
               t.ProductDescription.Contains(b)
             )).Select(x => x.ProductDescription).ToList();
```